# spring hibernate jpa: class not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

i try to implement dao layer with hibernate implemantation of jpa , but somehow i get ClassNotFoundException for my own class, which is surely situated in specified location. 
listings:
**jpa dao :**

```
package com.foo.testapp.daoImpl
@Repository
public class JNewsDaoImpl implements NewsDao{

    @PersistenceContext()
    private EntityManager eManager;
    @Resource
    UserTransaction uTransaction;
    @Override
    public List<News> listNews(boolean isrus) throws DAOTechnicException,
            DAOLogicException {
        System.out.println("in jpa");
        CriteriaBuilder cb = eManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<News> cQuery = cb.createQuery(News.class);
        Root<News> rootEntry = cQuery.from(News.class);
        CriteriaQuery<News> all = cQuery.select(rootEntry);
        TypedQuery<News> allQuery = eManager.createQuery(all);
        return allQuery.getResultList();
    }
        //etc
       }

package com.foo.testapp.service
@Service("newsService")
public class NewsServiceImpl implements NewsService {
    @Autowired
    private NewsDao dao;

    public void setNewsDao(NewsDao newsDao) {
        this.dao = newsDao;
    }
    public void getNewsDao(NewsDao newsDao){
        this.dao = newsDao;
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<News> listNews(boolean isrus) throws DAOTechnicException, DAOLogicException {
        //NewsDaoImpl dao = new NewsDaoImpl();
        List<News> listNews = new ArrayList<News>();
        listNews= dao.listNews(isrus);  
        return listNews;
    }
    //etc
       }
```

**spring configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cloud="http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-spring-0.8.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.testapp.daoImpl"/>

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/XE" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="system" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="1234" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"

    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="nEntityManager" 
        /> -->
    <beans:property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.foo.testapp.domain" />
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendor" />

</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="jpaVendor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="JNewsDaoImpl" class="com.foo.testapp.daoImpl.JNewsDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

**exceptions:**

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/jpaBeans.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.foo.testapp.daoImpl.JNewsDaoImpl] for bean with name 'JNewsDaoImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/jpaBeans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.testapp.daoImpl.JNewsDaoImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider: org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.initializeConnectionProviderFromConfig(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.InjectionSettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(InjectionSettingsFactory.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
    ... 28 more
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.foo.testapp.daoImpl.JNewsDaoImpl] for bean with name 'JNewsDaoImpl' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/jpaBeans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.testapp.daoImpl.JNewsDaoImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.testapp.daoImpl.JNewsDaoImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
    ... 46 more
```

so any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML configuration package names does not match the actual ones.

In XML you have `com.epam...`, while inb Java sources you have `com.foo...`.

EDIT:

Please check if you have any other exception beforehand. It seems like you're creating beans using both annotations - `@Repository` - and XML Spring configuration.

Comment: no there is the same names actually, i covered packages names with foo, just in question